# How to make ImageView partially visible and fade in completely after?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-animation

I am currently making an application where I want part of the logo of the application to appear at the center of the screen, translates to the top and then shows the entire logo. I currently have the application showing the entire logo and translating it as desired, but I am not sure how to hide most of the logo and make it show after. My logo consists of an icon on the left and text on the right. Once the logo reaches the top, I would like the name to appear smoothly while pushing the icon to the left as it goes. Is there a way to do this using the current code I have.

logo_animation.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <alpha
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:startOffset="2000"
        android:toYDelta="-30%p" />

</set>
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingStart="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingEnd="15dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".Main">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main.java:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Main extends AppCompatActivity implements AnimationListener {

    ImageView mainLogo;

    Animation mainLogoAnimation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        searchLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.searchLogo);

        mainLogoAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.logo_animation);
        mainLogoAnimation.setAnimationListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put the text in a separate TextView, and animate it on its own.